# Dependent builds in VSTS

Tags: git, build, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a VSTS GIT repository, all UI, services, code is in the same repository. Successful build produces the installer (.msi) to install the application.

Over the period of time my repository has grown up with lot of code. For each small code change & new build get trigger (gated check-in). Current build definition builds all components (UI & services) even if the change is in only one component. Please note there is no direct reference between components. Overall I think its monolithic way to maintain the repository.

I am now planning to break the GIT repository into set of repos. Each repo would have its own build definition. Now consider the following use case

There are changes in UI & services, there is some issue with service code changes. When developer check-ins the code it would build both UI & service.

1. In the first approach build would break (as service code has issues) neither UI & nor service code changes would be checked-in.
2. In the second approach UI build would be successful & code would be checked-in but for services code changes would be rejected as build would break.

**Question**
In VSTS is it possible to create dependent build definition? I mean if build 1 (Repo1) fails then reject the code changes for build 2 (repo 2)

Atul Sureka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach could be using [Trigger another build task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) and specifying a [Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/conditions)

Answer (score -1):

There isn’t the dependence relationship between different build definitions.

Since the UI and Service are depend, you should build and validate them in the same build definition.

To reduce the build time, you can setup a private build agent and do not clean source during the build (Choose false in Clean box of Get sources)

To get code in another repository, you can call git command (e.t. git clone) through Command Line task.

Comment: There is no direct reference of services in the UI. Services need not to be to compiled to build UI code. Putting all the things in a single repo does not sounds correct, it would certainly won't work in long run. Clean source option is disabled. I already have 5 agents but if the build time is long I would not get actual advantage of multiple agents. if we break the build & multiple agent process it then it would fast.correct ? In that way it makes more sense to break the current build.

Comment: @AtulSureka Yes, the Service don't need to compiled to build the UI, but they are depend for your requirement, for example, there isn't the content displayed in the UI if the service has been broken. You can cancel the other builds through REST API, but you can't control the order of different builds, for example, the UI build start/verified before the service build when both UI and service code changes. So, do it in the same build definition is the easy way, the project will be build faster if don't clean the source.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am not using clean build. It's not just UI and service. If there are multiple services (with no direct references between them) why should I build all if there is code changes in only one service. I think it won't work with large enterprise product where it take more than an hour to build the entire products. More importantly if gated check-in is enabled.

Comment: @AtulSureka In my opinion, the better way is that you can create multiple branches (e.g. dev, master) for each service, the gated check-in is used for dev branch and publish/deploy the service to dev server. Then merge changes from dev to master through Pull request (can created programmatically) with build validation (new build definition to build necessary services and UI). The same for UI.